# Copy Android Preference screen style using default xml attributes

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I have researched this but I am unable to find the right answer anywhere...I am trying to make the 'Help' UI of my app to look similar to the default Android's default 'Preference' UI.

Any ideas on how to get the attributes used by the the Preferences screen (eg textsize, textapparenceattribute and so forth?).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Something like this? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can download Android SDK and take a look into "/sdk/platforms/android-xx/data/res/layout" where all of Android default layouts reside.

Below is the file names that may be of any interest to you:

```
preference_category_holo.xml
preference_category.xml
preference_child_holo.xml
preference_child.xml
preference_dialog_edittext.xml
preference_header_item.xml
preference_holo.xml
preference_information_holo.xml
preference_information.xml
preference_list_content_single.xml
preference_list_content.xml
preference_list_fragment.xml
preferences.xml
preference_widget_checkbox.xml
preference_widget_seekbar.xml
preference_widget_switch.xml
preference.xml
```

And here is the example of how the Preference List XML looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/headers"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                style="?attr/preferenceFragmentStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:scrollbarStyle="@integer/preference_fragment_scrollbarStyle"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:listPreferredItemHeight="48dp"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" />

            <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/list_footer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/button_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <Button android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/back_button_label"
        />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <Button android:id="@+id/skip_button"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/skip_button_label"
                android:visibility="gone"
            />

            <Button android:id="@+id/next_button"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/next_button_label"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @user2943342, Yes, I needed the same thing and researched myself for 2 days or so. If you like my answer please click the "up arrow" sign at the top of the answer to upvote. You can even reaccept it if you feel it really answers your question. Peace!